# Graphql Mutations aren't working with Supabase and Postgraphile

Tags: javascript, graphql, nuxt.js

i have been wracking my brain for hours on end with no success. My Graphql Mutation for a form isn't working but my Graphql queries are working fine. Any idea why with the below code?  I'm using supabase as my database, postgraphile for graphql, nuxtjs for the ui

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <form method="POST" @submit.prevent="createAgreement()">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Reset"></a>
          <a class="navbar-brand">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Save Agreement"></a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <!-- Tab navs -->
          <div id="v-tabs-tab" class="nav flex-column nav-tabs text-center" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
            <a id="v-tabs-home-tab" class="nav-link active" data-mdb-toggle="tab" href="#v-tabs-home" role="tab"
              aria-controls="v-tabs-home" aria-selected="true">Create A New Agreement</a>
          </div>
          <!-- Tab navs -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-9">
          <div id="v-tabs-tabContent" class="tab-scope">
            <div id="v-tabs-home" class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-tabs-home-tab">
              <div class="table table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="text-align: right;">Agreement Name</td>
                      <td>
                        <input v-model="name" type="text" required />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="text-align: right;">Agreement Type</td>
                      <td>
                        <input v-model="type" type="text" name="Type" />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <br><br>
              <div id="accordionExample" class="accordion">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <h2 id="headingOne" class="accordion-header">
                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
                      data-mdb-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                      Content
                    </button>
                  </h2>
                  <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                    data-mdb-parent="#accordionExample">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                      <div class="table table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="text-align: right;">Excerpt</td>
                              <td>
                                <textarea id="excerpt" v-model="excerpt" type="textarea" cols="50" rows="10"
                                  value="Add a short Description"></textarea>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="text-align: right;">Description</td>
                              <td>
                                <textarea id="excerpt" v-model="content" type="textarea" cols="50" rows="10"
                                  value="Add a Description"></textarea>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <h2 id="headingThree" class="accordion-header">
                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
                      data-mdb-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                      Images and Videos
                    </button>
                  </h2>
                  <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree"
                    data-mdb-parent="#accordionExample">
                    <div class="accordion-body">
                      <td>
                        <input v-model="image" type="image" name="headshot" value="Select an image to upload"
                          help="Select a png, jpg or gif to upload." validation="mime:image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" />
                      </td>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
    <script>
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import allAgreementsList from "~/apollo/queries/sales/agreements";

const ADD_AGREEMENTS = gql`
    mutation ($name:String!,$excerpt:String,$type:String,$content:String,$image:String){
    createAgreement(objects: {name: $name, excerpt: $excerpt, type: $type, content: $content, image: $image}) {
        affected_rows
        returning {
            name
            excerpt
            type
            content
            image
    }
  }
}`;

export default {
    data() {
    return {
        type: [],
        name: " ",
        excerpt: " ",
        content: " ",
        image: " ",
        
      }
  },
    head: {
        title: 'Add New Agreement'
    },
  methods: {
      async addAgreement() {
            const name = this.name;
            const content = this.content;
            const excerpt = this.excerpt;
            const type = this.type;
            const image = this.image;
            await this.$apollo.mutate({
                mutation: ADD_AGREEMENTS,
                variables: {
                    name,
                    excerpt,
                    type,
                    content,
                    image,
                },
        update: (cache, { data: { insertAgreements }}) => {
                        // Read data from cache for this query
                        try {
                            const insertedAgreement = insertAgreements.returning;
                            console.log(insertedAgreement)
                            cache.writeQuery({
                                query: allAgreementsList
                            })
                        }
                        catch (err) {
                            console.error(err)
                        }
                    }
                }).then(() => {
                    this.$router.push({path: '../sales/agreements'})
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
                this.name = ' ';
                this.excerpt = ' ';
                this.type = ' ';
                this.content = ' ';
                this.image = ' ';
            },
            
        }
}
</script>
```

Also to note I have complete permissions on my database

Comment: any relevant error in your dev console?

Comment: No, no errors on the network tab, no errors in terminal either

Comment: Can you try adding `.catch(error => { console.log(error) })` to `mutate` hoping to get more informations on what is happening?

Comment: Did you do any debugging? Which part of the code does not work or is not reached?

Comment: I updated my question with the .catch error. Yes i debugged with different databases rather hosted with supabase or with postgres locally. I can query fine, just can't seem to perform mutations from the code, but I can directly in the graphql server.

Comment: so, did you get any error logged out from the catch?

Comment: no nothing actually shows up as the data being sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i switched systems and ended up using Apollo-Server, Prisma (my ORM), and Typegraphql just in case anyone wants a working solution with this combination:

```html
import "reflect-metadata";
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server";
import * as path from "path";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

import { resolvers } from "../prisma/generated/type-graphql";

interface Context {
  prisma: PrismaClient;
}

async function main() {
  const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers,
    emitSchemaFile: path.resolve(__dirname, "./generated-schema.graphql"),
    validate: false,
  });

  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  await prisma.$connect();

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: (): Context => ({ prisma }),
  });
  const { port } = await server.listen(8001);
  console.log(`GraphQL is listening on ${port}!`);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

It also turned out to be a cors issue.